# Cleaning and merging data in Stata

Tags: dataset, stata

I have two questions.

1) I would like to reduce the number of observations in "location" from 5 to 1 for every country and get the corresponding values for the years in just one row. How do I do this?
[Screenshot of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qkcz.png)

2) I would like to merge this dataset with another one, where "location" is not defined by country code, but country name. How can I merge them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `collapse (min) YR*, by(location)`
2. There is no straightforward way to do this. You need to make sure that both datasets contain a variable with the same values to merge on, so either 3-letter country codes or country names. You can try to find a dataset that contains both and merge it with one of your datasets. Another option is the user-written `kountry` which is made for these kinds of things. If you type `search kountry` in Stata, the first result will be package dm0038_1. If you click on it there will be a link to click on to install it.